# Constructor in Abstract Class access denied

Tags: java, class

[image]Ive got an abstact class:

```
 public abstract class AbstrakterZahlenRatenAdapter {   
     protected final ZahlenRaten zahlenRaten;
```

and should implement a constructor.

```
public AbstrakterZahlenRatenAdapter(ZahlenRaten zahlenRaten) {
    this.zahlenRaten = zahlenRaten;   // this.zahlenRaten --> acces denied
}
```

What do I have to change? I don't understand why the acces is denied.

Comment: Where do you get this error? For me - though - that class compiles fine ...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: The final field, can be initialized through constructor. What is exactly the error you got?

Comment: I dont know how to describe the problem more concise. I added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Note the capital letter at the start - it's the class ZahlenRaten that it can't access, not the field.